# Set unique class to menu item on wordpress and woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have menu in WordPress and menu items are category 1 and category 2. the structure of this menu items are as product category (woocomerce). 
Under each category it has some products.  I want to add some features / highlight the parent / category which item is belong.
I made a lot of research but it didn't work.

Below is my code so far:

```
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if ( is_product() ){
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item-test';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
```

Comment: You can use max mega menu dropdown WordPress  Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_nav_menu()` in parent li this class `menu-item-has-children` added css for highlight category.

Comment: Hi, I checked the html class I don't see any has-children. Instead both category items has the same html class.

Comment: This class is default in wordpress, Please provide me your developing website link

Comment: Hi @nik, I love to give you the link but I'm not allowed to.

Comment: Yes, that's the default clas. I'm aware of it. that's for reference only.

Comment: This is the class of my menu (Category 1), if clicked this item. class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat current-menu-item  menu-item-590"

Comment: If i clicked product inside this category. The class transform to menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat current-product-ancestor current-menu-parent current-product-parent  menu-item-590

Comment: Your have 2 class current-menu-parent current-product-parent added css highting

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but it also applies CSS class to another menu item. That's weird!

Comment: Yes, It's Common class to highlight and after clicking category showing this class.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I added products to both categories, that's why I'm having same class in each category.